# How to $match a field conditionally in mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

I have the following schema:

```json
User: {
...otherFields,
isDumb: false,
type: "A" // could be "A", "B", or "C"
}
```

I want to fetch all `dumb` users by default and fetch by `type` only if the `type` is passed through the parameters.

```js
    static async getUsers(req: any, res: Response) {
        const { type = "" } = req.params;
        const queryPipeline = [
            {
                $match: {
                    isDumb: true,
                    type: // I want to only filter by type if the param is passed in
                }
            }
         ]
         const users = await User.aggregate(queryPipeline);
```

So if my data was:

```json
[
  {
    ...otherFields,
    isDumb: false,
    type: "A"
  },
  {
    ...otherFields,
    isDumb: true,
    type: "B"
  },
  {
    ...otherFields,
    isDumb: true,
    type: "C"
  }
]
```

and `req.params.type` was "B", I should get back:

```json
[
  {
    ...otherFields,
    isDumb: true,
    type: "B"
  }
],
```

if `req.params.type` was `undefined`, I should get all `dumb` users

```json
[
  {
    ...otherFields,
    isDumb: true,
    type: "B"
  },
  {
    ...otherFields,
    isDumb: true,
    type: "C"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to build an object and pass it to match

```
const matchParams = req.params.type ? {isDumb:true,type:req.params.type } : {isDumb:true }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object using JS:

```js
const params = "A" // get req.params as you want
let query = {$match:{isDumb:true}}
if(params) query.$match.type = params

console.log(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use Aggregation Framework for simple find query. You can use `find` method instead.

Second, consider approach where you initialize the filter with `isDumb: true`, and add new `type` property only if `req.params.type` exists.

```js
let filter = { isDumb: true };
if(req.params.type) filter.type = req.params.type;

const users = await User.find(filter);
```